# AngularFire2 - get single document from Firestore without observer

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I use Ionic/Angular and AngularFire2 v5 to get data from Firestore (works fine).
I just had a problem with getting a single document from Firestore without using observables.
It should work like that: sending document-ID to Firestore and get the whole document-data back.

Is this possible or do i have to create an own service just with Firestore without AngularFire?

Comment: What do you mean you want to get a single document from Firestore without using an Observable ?

Comment: something like in the firestore docu: var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc(docID);       docRef.get().then(function(doc) {return doc.data()});

Comment: ... Those two lines of code use both promises and observables, are you aware of that ?

Comment: promise is okay, but how can i use promise with angularfire?

Comment: Observables are pumped up promises, I recommend you to use observables. But if you want to stick to promises, `Observable.prototype.toPromise()` will transform an observable into a promise.

Comment: with Observables i have to subscribe and instantly to unsubscribe, when i receive the data. I miss the simple http.get, just call, get data, finished

Comment: That's not true. With observables, you unsubscribe when you don't want to get the data anymore. Firebase is made for realtime exchange, that's why they use observables. If you want to use 20% of the features of a library, consider switching to another one (for instance, you could create a Parse server).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171058/discussion-between-andodri-and-trichetriche).